# splitting this line using boost or regex

Tags: c++, boost, split

I am new to C++ and I am struggling to get this string to split. Looking to create a multimap that has book as the key. Noun and the definition after the "-=>>" would be a pair and so would verb and its definition. Here is the strings I can not seem to split correctly:

```
book|noun -=>> A set of pages.|verb -=>> To arrange something on a particular date.
bookable|adjective -=>> Can be ordered.
```

This is the code I am trying. I figured out this code is not properly loading the multimap, because when I print parts[0] both names are put into the same index. It seems regex is a simpler solution, but after plugging away at this for the last couple of hours I need some help.

```
while (getline(myfile, line)) {
   string delimiters("|-=>>.");

   vector<string> parts;
   boost::split(parts, line, boost::is_any_of(delimiters));

   name = parts[0];
   partOfSpeech = parts[1];
   definition = parts[2];

   dictionary.emplace(make_pair(name, make_pair(partOfSpeech, definition)));
}
```

Any guidance or feedback is much appreciated

Comment: could you give us an example string, like: `"Lord of the Rings|House -=>> 1, 17, 5 | saying -=>> ...` ?! I do not yet understand the contents of `verb` and `adjective` and have no clue what `bookable` stands for, as it is not yet separated from the contents of `verb`, right?!

Comment: `|` is special for most regexes.

Comment: @Yunnosch ... why should that be a problem? You can mask the character in the regex couldn't you?! `\|`

Comment: @TomMekken I was kind of jumping ahead. I saw the title and the `|`. You are right.

Comment: Yeah I understood so far, but could you provide us an example? (To verify the regex against)

Comment: does this help you? [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4a1bd)

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with this tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split your line by `|`. The first resulting part is your **name**. Then got through all the other resulting parts and divide them into halves by `-=>>`. This will give you the first (**partOfSpeech**) and second (**definition**) halves of your pairs.